# What is a non-secular and possibly offensive version of "for heaven's sake"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

In [Is there a secular, non vulgar alternative to "for heaven's sake"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155509/is-there-a-secular-non-vulgar-alternative-to-for-heavens-sake) Terdon asks for something that is polite, secular, and non-offensive.

I am asking for what is a non-secular phrase that you can think of that also has known use.

For instance my aunt says, "Jesus, Mary, and Joseph!!"

Any religion goes as long as the phrase is discernible in English.  You can mix in offensive words but really looking for the religious aspect.  Bonus if the phrase could be used at work.

To clarify vulgarity is OK but the religious aspect is key.

(For the "closers" - this question would be the OPPOSITE of Terdon's)

Comment: How does one determine if a phrase is "more religious" (or "more non-secular") than another? I would posit that it is simply binary, either religious or not. I mean, if I formed a phrase using all 12 apostles would it be better due to length and number of references, or would "Jesus!" trump it, since he was in charge?

Comment: @DigitalChris - I think that is part of the question in question.  But personally I would think it would signify the "speaker's" level of knowledge in the faith. I was going to say devoutness but then I am sure some would counter that a devout person would not say the phrase at all.

Comment: You might want to clarify if you want *vulgar* answers or not.

Comment: If it is a test of knowledge in the faith, what you are asking for is the most *obscure* religious exclamation.

Comment: @DigitalChris - Never said obscure.  I would like it to be something that is "said" not just a list of religious names.

Comment: @Jim - except I am asking the opposite.

Comment: I think this is a bit too far the wrong side of Primarily Opinion-based. It's hard to think of anything ***more** "non-secular"* (i.e. - ***more "religious"***) than ["**By all that is holy**!"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by+all+that+is+holy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (that's 68,000 written instances, so it obviously does or did appeal).

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that. But I have to agree with FumbleFingers that this looks opinion based. I can't change my reason. I recommend rewriting or deleting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - maybe for a Catholic.  I am working with some zealots in my global team and I need a couple of good phrases that I can say.  Was hoping to get some outside of Christianity.  I can reword question if it helps.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: You certainly seem to have a very parochial view of Christianity/Catholicism! I never mentioned either - why would you assume that only *Christian* faiths are implied by the word **holy**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Ha!  I knew you were going to say that.  You are right but haven't considered the feelings of the occult members.

Comment: I think you could just remove "most" from your question. You mentioned that you are looking for couple of phrases also.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Well, here are nearly 100,000 instances of ["**By all that is sacred**!"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by+all+that+is+sacred%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which might sit more comfortably with occultists.

Comment: @Ryebread I have to say POB. It's a good question, but too hard to have a concrete single answer.

Comment: @ermanen - I have edited the question to make it clearer -hopefully.  Took out most.

Comment: How about the catch all - *For the love of all that is sacred or profane*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have a hard time seeing how one question can be OK to ask and the opposite is an too opinion based (when the first certainly was).  Seems to be very inconsistent.  Also the quality of this question is much higher than the 100s of ELL questions that are "accepted" on this site each week right?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Don't look at me! I closevoted the previous question and commented that it seemed rather pointless. But that closevote had no backup from others, so it expired, and I later answered the question myself because everyone else seemed so keen on it.

Comment: Jesus H. Christ, this is a silly question!

Answer (score 1):

For God's sake!

Here is my logic.

If all things holy represent a pyramid, then God (by definition) must be at the top of the pyramid.  Even the Catholic trinity represents God as the father of Jesus.

Hence, the most religious reference you can make is God.

At least in a concise form. You could proceed to list God, all of his minions, every apostle, saint, pope, cardinal, bishop, priest, nun, person who went to church, etc.  and claim that their aggregate weight was greater. But if you accept the notion of an omnipotent and omnipresent God, he should already be accounted for in all of those things.

Comment: +1 for being able to slightly offend people of several different religions at the same time.

Comment: @RyeBread It is an art.  Although, honestly with perhaps the exception of the last bit, I can't imagine it being too offensive. Anyone who finds the concept of Heaven applicable will likely accept God as being at the top of that chain.  The name/terminology may change to be applicable, though.