# Are there other interjections to substitute for "jeez", "good grief", "oh my god", "and other interjections containing religion?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, expressions, synonyms, vocabulary

I would like to know if there are interjections expressing exasperation, annoyance, anger, frustration without connection to religion. Preferably doesn't originate from it either. No euphemism too. Much appreciated.

Comment: [***Land sakes and lawks amussy**!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155509/is-there-a-secular-non-vulgar-alternative-to-for-heavens-sake#comment323506_155509) *(For the Lord's sake!* [and]  *Lord have mercy!)*. But ***Gordon Bennett!*** is entirely secular.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. The 'duplicate' question is looking for a phrase, "For X's sake", where "X's" is a stand-in for the undesirable "heaven's". The word I'm thinking of in answer to this question, 'pshaw', wouldn't work in answer to the other.

Comment: <rolls eyes heavenward, despite being an atheist> ***Fiddlesticks**!*